# "Permission denied" when download from script(ruby) file

Tags: bash, permissions, scripts, ruby

I want to download a project's dependencies from a script file

in tutorial said: run this comment to download

```
./download-dependencies core
```

my way was like this:

```
$ cd Documents/ImageProccesing/
$ ./download-dependencies core
bash: ./download-dependencies: Permission denied    
$
```

I did this too,but....

```
$ sudo -i    
[sudo] password for amir2:     
# cd /home/amir2/Documents/ImageProccesing/    
# ./download-dependencies core    
-bash: ./download-dependencies: Permission denied    
#
```

in addition...
first of download-dependencies file is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

$modules = [:core,
            :images2002,
            :images2004]

def usage
  puts "Usage: ./download-dependencies <#{$modules.join('|')}>"
end
```

Answer (score -1):

Try the below command,

```
sudo chmod a+rw -R
```

After this run,

```
.rvm
```

Then try to install ruby. Hope this helps.

Comment: So tnx, this help me :)

    chmod +x filename

It's nice of u :)

Comment: We are glad to know that your issue gets fixed. Thanks for your command.